Powershell Oracle to SQL. Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
I'm trying to find a way to import data from Oracle to a SQL Server using PowerShell. I used the script below to import it and it works perfectly when the result is small.
add-type -path 'C:\Oracle\Client\ODP.NET\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll';
$Orclconn = "User Id=Oracle_Net;Password=*****;Data Source=Nexus;Connection Timeout=0";
$qry = "SELECT Cust_id, Relation_id, Order_id, quantity
FROM Cust_Order ob
WHERE Pay_method = '110'
AND Set = 0";
$adapter = new-object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($qry, $Orclconn);
$tbl = new-object System.Data.DataTable('T_Order_Intake');
$adapter.Fill($tbl);
$sqlconn = "server=Customer_Nexus;database=Cust_Order;trusted_connection=true;Connection Timeout=0";
$sqlld = new-object system.data.sqlclient.Sqlbulkcopy($sqlconn);
$sqlld.DestinationTableName="dbo.T_Order_Intake";
$sqlld.WriteToServer($tbl);

However, if I change the query to get larger data from another table, I get the error...
15345678   *** this is the same row count when the query is run directly on the Oracle server ***
Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding"
At E:\A_SCRIPT\Scripts\Orcl.ps1:23 char:1
+ $sqlld.WriteToServer($tbl);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

I tried setting the connection timeout as 0 on both the server connections but am getting the same error. Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Check: BulkCopyTimeout setting perhaps?

Wow, that worked. Knew it was something simple that I didn't know about. Thanks @siggemannen.

Any Idea why this doesn't work when it is added as an Execute process task in Visual Studio using an execute process task? Basically I'm trying to automate it.. and it just isn't working. When I run the SSIS package, it just opens the powershell but the task keeps going on and on and does not end.

i'm guessing it just opens a powershell window and does nothing, but who knows, you probably messed up the command line, but ssis is out of scope of this question anyway. You can see in task manager the commandline that the process got, perhaps it will give a clue

What do you mean "You messed up the command line"? The scripts with lesser data are working on SSIS.... And yes, it opens a powershell window and does noting as you said... not sure why...

Hard to say, i don't see your screen :) But good luck with it
